# Cross-Validation with libsvm to find best parameters

Tags: matlab, libsvm, cross-validation

In order to find the best parameters to be used with libsvm I used the code below. Instead of './heart_scale' I had a file containing positive and negative examples each with a hog vector in libsvm format. I had 1000 positive examples and 4000 negative. However these were put in order, i.e. the 1st 1000 examples were positive examples and the others were negative.

**Question: Now, I came in doubt whether the accuracy returned by this code is actual accuracy. This is because when I read on 5 fold cross-validation, it takes the first 4/5 of the data as training and the 1/5 left for testing. Does this mean that it can be the case the testing set is all negative? Or it takes the examples randomly please?**

```
%# read some training data
[labels,data] = libsvmread('./heart_scale');

%# grid of parameters
folds = 5;
[C,gamma] = meshgrid(-5:2:15, -15:2:3);

%# grid search, and cross-validation
cv_acc = zeros(numel(C),1);
for i=1:numel(C)
    cv_acc(i) = svmtrain(labels, data, ...
                    sprintf('-c %f -g %f -v %d', 2^C(i), 2^gamma(i), folds));
end

%# pair (C,gamma) with best accuracy
[~,idx] = max(cv_acc);

%# contour plot of paramter selection
contour(C, gamma, reshape(cv_acc,size(C))), colorbar
hold on
plot(C(idx), gamma(idx), 'rx')
text(C(idx), gamma(idx), sprintf('Acc = %.2f %%',cv_acc(idx)), ...
    'HorizontalAlign','left', 'VerticalAlign','top')
hold off
xlabel('log_2(C)'), ylabel('log_2(\gamma)'), title('Cross-Validation Accuracy')

%# now you can train you model using best_C and best_gamma
best_C = 2^C(idx);
best_gamma = 2^gamma(idx);
%# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find answer to your question in the LIBSVM source code.
See the function `svm_cross_validation` in the [svm.cpp](https://github.com/cjlin1/libsvm/blob/master/svm.cpp#L2339).

As you can see, for classification cross-validation problem LIBSVM firstly performs class [grouping](https://github.com/cjlin1/libsvm/blob/master/svm.cpp#L2360) and than shuffling.

So, answer to your question: yes, the accuracy returned by this code is actual accuracy.

Note: the accuracy estimation depends also on data nature, cross-validation folds number and itself is a random value with some distribution.